# How do I capture a drone?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

One of the enemies in the game is a small floating four-pronged claw.  Despite my best efforts, I do not seem to be able to use the Arc Thrower against one.

**Is it possible to capture a drone?  If so, what do I require to do so?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to autopsy the drone, which will give you intel that a stronger arc thrower would be able to affect them. You can upgrade your arc throwers at the Foundry.

The drone is not stunned, however. You actually take control of the drone and can command it for the rest of battle.

Comment: does the same apply to sectopods?  Would be totally worth the investment into the upgraded arc thrower if I could control one of those *evil grin*

Comment: @yx. I don't believe it does.